# the Medrash on human speech

Tags: sources-mekorot, midrash

I heard someone say that the Medrash states, *“Words, like the ocean, can be stormy or calm. An evil mouth, like turbulent waves, can destroy and kill. A sharp tongue, like deep water, is feared. Good words, like pearls on the ocean floor, are precious…”*

Does anyone happen to know where the source for this Medrash can found?

Comment: Where did you find this exact English quote? Was it in Artscroll's _Wisdom in the Hebrew Alphabet_?

Answer (score 4):

Artscroll's *Wisdom in the Hebrew Alphabet* on the letter peh (page 184) quotes the *Midrash Alpha Beisa* as saying exactly your quote. I don't know where in the Sefer it is exactly, but it's in [there](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/26862) somewhere. [This Wikipedia article](https://he.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%90%D7%9C%D7%A4%D7%90_%D7%91%D7%99%D7%AA%D7%90_%D7%93%D7%91%D7%9F_%D7%A1%D7%99%D7%A8%D7%90) discusses the background of the Sefer and its author.